# Steam's recently played with doesn't update?

Tags: steam, technical-issues

[image]

Is there a reason Steam's "recently played with" feature does not work? I have been playing online games and it is still blank.

I have over 116 hours on PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds since I got it this past month, but none of the people I've met and played with on it show up in the "Recently Played With" section, and I have no clue why. It just stays blank like in the picture. I've read online that Valve may have broke something, but I'd like to be sure it is not on my end.

If I go to the main Steam display, click View and then Players, I only have people I played with on Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 68 days ago.

Comment: Please add more detail, if you want a precise and good answer from this site.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong Not much else to say. I play online with people and the recently played with still looks like the picture above.

Comment: You might want to take a look at other posts of errors around the site. Most of them add version, sometimes logs, what happened before this, and sudden changes and differences. There are many factors that can be considered. I am currently thinking of 8 different possibilities for what could have happened. BTW, you might want to add the tag "Technical-issues"

Comment: @KingsleyZhong I added an example but I will also add what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, it's only showing recent *friends* you're playing with

Comment: I assume that by "I have been playing games" you mean multiplayer games.

Comment: Are you set to [appear as "online"](https://i.imgur.com/Wopx0cm.png)? "Offline state disables and restricts some features (online multiplayer, inviting friends to games, chat).

Comment: @Equinoxinator Thanks for adding the information, it's helping. I might come down to an answer in couple minuets.

Comment: @user598527 **online** games and yes I appear as online

Comment: Bear in mind if you open up a game and look inside of the Steam Overlay down the bottom right, it shows the two buttons "Show Friends" and "Recent Players". Pressing the "Recent Players" button will automatically open up a dialog with every person you have played with. Also bear in mind, that PUBG has a separate server-service, where you create your own account to play (automatic upon buying the game). Same with games such as Elite Dangerous. It won't show me who I play with, because it isn't running on a Steam service. Games such as CSGO that actually do use Valve as a middle man will show up

Comment: I am having the same issue... did you find a fix?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Steam API feature that developers of may or may not implement in the multiplayer games that they publish on Steam.

In other words, the game must "reveal" to Steam the information that certain players have played together in a multiplayer game. Steam does not determine that on its own.

PUBG does not implement this feature, while CSGO does.